# How to Store / Groups together / manipulate Floating point Constants in VBA

Tags: vba, visio

I am using Visio-2016 VBA.
In my Main Module I have to draw approx ten rectangle shapes per Visio page. 32 pages are iterated in a For Loop. Various properties for Rectangles also need to be set for each rectangle such as Border or borderless.

DrawRectangle() function needs to have rectangle's co-ordinate pairs in the form of X1, Y1, X2, Y2
My values are in Double(double-precision floating-point) CONSTANTS.

I have tried my best to store and group these co-ordinate pairs as constants but no avail.

**Sample co-ordinate pair for one rectangle shape is:**

X1 = 3.179133858

Y1 = 1.181102362

X2 = 6.131889764

Y2 = 1.57480315

I tried following things to group co-ordinate pairs for at least ten rectangles, no success:
- Plain list of constants at top of Main sub (don't want it)
- Enumerated list (works only for Long data types)
- Array or two dimensional array (inconvenient, set/return val by Array index only)
- Type ... End Type (works but Error when I create a collection/dictionary)

**Here is portion of code from a Class I am trying to create**

```
Public Type CoordRectType
          X1 As Double
          Y1 As Double
          X2 As Double
          Y2 As Double
End Type

Public RectLftBtm As CoordRectType
Public RectLftTop As CoordRectType
Public colRect As Collection

Sub TestIt()
' Create instances of UDT as required
' LEFT-BOTTOM BarCode     [vsoShape1]
      RectLftBtm.X1 = 3.179133858
      RectLftBtm.Y1 = 1.181102362
      RectLftBtm.X2 = 6.131889764
      RectLftBtm.Y2 = 1.57480315

' LEFT-TOP  BarCode     [vsoShape2]
      RectLftTop.X1 = 3.179133858
      RectLftTop.Y1 = 1.181102362
      RectLftTop.X2 = 6.131889764
      RectLftTop.Y2 = 1.57480315

colRect.Add RectLftBtm , "LeftBottomRect"   ''' Compiler Error here ''''''
colRect.Add RectLftTop , "LeftTopRect"      ''' Compiler Error here '''''' 

End Sub

''' .... REST OF THE CODE FOR CLASS ......
' ///////////////////////////////////////////
```

I also tried to replace Collection with Dictionary in above code but same compiler error

I want to store all co-ordinate pairs data preferably as Constants (if not possible than in variables) inside a Class module. From Main sub, I will then set Class properties and call methods in iteration to create rectangle shapes as needed and still my Main Module would be neat and clean

**One supplementary question in last:**
Does a constant of any intrinsic(built-in VBA) data type have same memory usage as a variable of that data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were so close.  One way to tackle this problem is to create the rectangle class using the Create/Self methods for self instantiating objects

This is the rectangle class

```
Option Explicit

Private Type Properties

    X1                      As Double
    X2                      As Double
    Y1                      As Double
    Y2                      As Double
    ' extend this pattern to include any other parameters relevant to drawing the rectangle
End Type

Private p                   As Properties

Public Function Create _
( _
    ByVal X1 As Double, _
    ByVal Y1 As Double, _
    ByVal X2 As Double, _
    ByVal Y2 As Double _
) As Rectangle

    With New Rectangle

        Set Create = .Self(X1, Y1, X2, Y2)

    End With

End Function

Public Function Self _
( _
    ByVal X1 As Double, _
    ByVal Y1 As Double, _
    ByVal X2 As Double, _
    ByVal Y2 As Double _
) As Rectangle

    With p

        .X1 = X1
        .Y1 = Y1
        .X2 = X2
        .Y2 = Y2
        ' extend this pattern to include any other parameters relevant to drawing your rectangle
    End With

    Set Self = Me

End Function


Public Sub Draw()   ' You don't want to provide parameters when you call draw.  This should be done
                    ' when you create your rectangle

' Put the code to draw the rectangle here

End Sub
```

You'll note we have included the function for the rectangle to draw itself.  You'll see why we have done this later.

Now we create the pages of rectangles.  So in a module include

```
Public Function SetupPage1() As Collection
' In practise we would probably setup a Page class and register the rectangles with the page class instance
Dim my_rectangles As Collection

    Set my_rectangles = New Collection

    With my_rectangles
        .Add Rectangle.Create(3.179133858, 1.181102362, 6.131889764, 1.57480315)
        .Add Rectangle.Create(3.179133858, 1.181102362, 6.131889764, 1.57480315)
        ' etc

    End With

    Set SetupPage1 = my_rectangles

End Function
```

And

```
Public Function SetupAllPages() As Collection


Dim my_pages As Collection

   Set my_pages = New Collection

   With my_pages

        .Add SetupPage1
        .Add SetupPage2
        .Add SetupPage3
        'etc

    End With

    Set SetupAllPages = my_pages

End Function
```

And finally, in the same or another module the code to draw the rectangles on all pages.

```
Public Sub DrawPages()

Dim PagesToDraw         As Collection
Dim this_page           As Variant
Dim this_rectangle      As Variant

    Set PagesToDraw = SetupAllPages

    For Each this_page In PagesToDraw ' this page takes a collection

        For Each this_rectangle In this_page

            this_rectangle.Draw

        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

With the sub above you can now see why we didn't want our Draw Sub to take parameters, it would mean that we lose the simplicity of the code here.

The final step is to set the predeclared attribute of the Rectangle class.  You can do this by exporting the class to Notepad++ setting the attribute to treu and reimporting.  Or by using the '@PredeclaredId attribute offered by the Fantabulous RubberDuck addin.

Come back here if you get stuck.

The code above can be polished quite a bit more but I hope that you will now be able to see a way forward.

Comment: I gave a try so I can understand proposed solution. But i got Error in Function SetupPage1(). when parsing line .Add Rectangle.Create....   Error Variable 'Rectangle' not defined. I already set the Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True

Comment: My Class name was misspelled and was not matching, Cleared that issue. now I am stuck on another step: this_rectangle.Draw Error "Object variable or with block variable not set"

Comment: That's because I missed out what is probably the most critical line of code in the Rectabgle class <blush>.  In the self function you need to add the line ' Set Self = Me' as the last line before the exit function.

Comment: For testing purposes  add the line 'Debug.Print "Drawing box ", p.X1, p.Y2, p.X2,p.Y2' to the drawing function.

Comment: For the sake of completion, the link to the article where the concept of the "create" solution is explained in detail: https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/04/24/factories-parameterized-object-initialization/

Comment: @sunnyimran I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: OK, I have tested using class: 'Rectangle' and Module: 'Module_Rect_Cls_Test'. Module uses:
    For Each this_rectangle In this_page
        this_rectangle.Draw
    Next
class method Draw() works fine for two iterations, on third iteration throws Error-13, Type mismatch error. why? can't resolve.

Secondly the co-ordinate pairs are supplied as arguments from Module to Class's Create() Method. Is it possible to store all pairs in class itself and select right pair by only a single argument: 'Rectangle name' from Module? Class would take care of picking right co-ordinates?

Comment: I only setup two rectangles on page 1 as an example.  I have tested my code and all works fine on my pc. So there is likely something in your code that is incorrect.  You can setup the class module to do whatever you wish including drawing specific rectangles in response to a single parameter.  But its up to you to develop that code not me.  You should make an attempt and when you get stuck ask another question on SO showing the code that causes the problems.

Comment: @Freeflow Of course that's me who should develop the code for my work.  I appreciate your hints. If you like you can hint a bit further on embedding all co-ordinate pairs data in class and call a method with just the name of rectangle. VBA for visio automation seems quite confined. I am trying to jump to C#.Net. would you like giving any hints on how to start office automation there?

Comment: Consider storing your rectangle information in an external file.  e.g. excel.  This makes it easier to edit the size of the rectangles without needing to go into the VBA.  Otherwise just declare an enumeration in the class and then use the enumerants outside the class to specify which rectangle you want and a corresponding select case inside the class to provide the coordinates for the appropriate rectangle.  Or just set up a scripting dictionary in your class which is populated when the class is initialised.  The public enumeration would now be the keys for the scripting dictionary.

Comment: Alright, appreciate your advice. Not an expert in VBA but I do have background in C/C++ and a bit of C#. Familiar with VBA Dictionary, Collections etc. VBA Enumeration was my first choice but it is limited to store only one constant type i-e Long data type. My co-ordinate pairs are in Double precision data type and this was the stopping point and getting some ideas from experts

Comment: I found VBA not that friendly but limited. Had a hard time solving many issues of my project. Modern File Dialog Picker and Folder Picker was one of them. Solved somehow.  
I am also looking to port my whole VBA project to C#. If someone can recommend  helpful stuff like a good book or web series on  **developing Visio solution using C# Visual Studio**  that would be great. I found various articles on net but the topics are scattered. A book is definitely great source.  Let me workout with VBA hints from here and I will revert back with results.